# How can I configure Cordova 6.4 to build for 64-bit for iOS 10.1?

Tags: ios, cordova

I am using Cordova 6.4.0. I have been able to successfully build [IPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.ipa) files for both AdHoc and iTunes Store submission.

Recently we started testing on iOS 10.1, and we are getting the error "This app may slow down your iPhone".

The issue is of course 32-bit versus 64-bit targeting.

However, in all my searching of YouTube, Stack Exchange and Facebook, and other Internet sites, I have not found the answer.

How can I pass flags to "cordova build ios --device" so that it will not give this warning on iOS 10.1?

Comment: What version of `cordova-ios` platform do you have installed in your project?

Comment: <engine name="ios" spec="4.1.1" />

Comment: You might want to the most recent version of `cordova-ios` (4.3.1) and see if that helps.